# Using OAuth with OData

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, odata, dotnetopenauth

Looking for any recent examples using OAuth with OData pref. from a WPF client without AppFabric or other dependencies

found this year+ old article

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/01/20/oauth-2-0-and-odata-protecting-an-odata-service-using-oauth-2-0.aspx

which requires AppFabric

another from DevEx also a year+ old but the sample doesn't compile
http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theonewith/archive/2011/02/24/odata-and-oauth-part-1-introduction.aspx

all the other search results refer to these 2 sites

wondering if there's been any new developments over the past year to build upon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET 4.5 WebAPI will support both oData as well as oAuth out of the box. If you are starting a new project I would recommend looking into that one.

Scott Gu's last info is that the ASP.NET WebAPI beta oData is already supported and oAuth will be shipped with the RTM.

Based on past experiences with ASP.NET versions, the availability of the RTM is not for too long.

You can read about the ASP.NET WebAPI (also see comments): 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/23/asp-net-web-api-part-1.aspx

Comment: any guidance on if that,s usable from a wpf client ?